# Inkscape: Text hidden behind polygon on lower layer

Tags: inkscape, layers, maps

I am working with labels on a choropleth map, all imported from a PDF in QGIS.

Because of issues related to the text when importing the file, I need to replace the label on each polygon.

For some reason, though, Inkscape is now showing all the text below the polygons instead of above them:
[image]

I have even tried adding the text on a separate layer ("Labels maps") above the base map, but it is still showing it under the polygons.

Even more peculiar, when exporting the file to PDF it is showing the text correctly above the polygons:
[image]

Is there a way to have the editor display the text correctly?

Thank you!

Example file: [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jsOKWq-sRQSxA2O9nl8JJhwIFCxA9k0C/view?usp=share_link)

Comment: Hard to tell without an example. Could you share that file?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Have you tried doing *Object > Raise to top*?  It's hard to tell for sure what's wrong without having the access to the actual file. Can you share the SVG over at SVGshare.com and post the link here?

Answer (score 2):

Thank you to those who have commented on this. I have found a solution in the [Inkscape forum](https://inkscape.org/forums/questions/text-hidden-behind-polygon-on-lower-layer/?c=49729): "The layer Labels maps has groups that have a filter (blend mode :screen) applied. Removing the filters from the groups shows the labels."

Comment: Glad you've solved it. That's why it is recommended to include the actual file or at least a minimum example in your questions.